# How could I invoke Microsoft Password Provider's LogonPasswordReset in my custom credential provider?

Tags: c++, windows, credentials, multi-factor-authentication

I have a custom credential provider to do 2fa authentication and I want to use self service password reset of windows. I found LogonPasswordReset in the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{8841d728-1a76-4682-bb6f-a9ea53b4b3ba}porint to keymgr.dll
```

and LogonPasswordReset under the password provider:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{60b78e88-ead8-445c-9cfd-0b87f74ea6cd}\LogonPasswordReset
```

Is there any way to invoke this LogonPasswordReset ?

Or Is there any Windows API to get the security questions list of passwords and how to pass them to reset the password of windows?

Comment: Did you try creating an instance of the clsid you found? Debug its QueryInterface...

Comment: do u mean   CComPtr<ICredentialProvider> spProvider
  spProvider.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PasswordResetCredentialProvider);
  in GetSerialization of my mfa credential provider 
  spCredential->GetSerialization(&cpgsr, &cpcs, &pszStatrus, &cpsi);  So it can access the reset password gui .

Comment: I meant 8841d728 that you found. Call QueryInterface on it and single step it in a debugger...